# Find the maximum height using depth first search

Tags: graph-theory

I am referring a graph theory note, in my note there is a problem to find the maximum height using depth first search

[image]

As a solution there is two solution

First one is

[image]

2nd one is

[image]

If I take $f$ as a root then I can get height as $4$ but if I get $a$ as root I can get height as $8$
Can anyone please help me to understand this
I can't understand  Why there are two solution of height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of a rooted tree depends on which root you select.

Consider the case of a path with $2n+1$ vertices which I think is the most extreme (the one you give is also pretty extreme). If the root is the center of the path then the height is going to be $n+1$, but if you pick one of the endpoints hte height is goind to be $2n+1$.

Comment: If there is problem  a finding the maximum height It is depend on what we considering as a root  Is it what you are saying?

Comment: Do you know any free available book for graph theory?

Comment: I think Diestel's book has a free version : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjblvP56-DwAhVRT6wKHfy_CBAQFjABegQIBxAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.esi2.us.es%2F~mbilbao%2Fpdffiles%2FDiestelGT.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1kUoEMIfM0xMf3_cCmAcd6

Comment: Does maximum height depend on the path ?

Comment: The maximum height is the largest distance between the root and another vertex. In trees there is only one possible path.

Comment: Thank you for you help